# Running Jekyll on ONLY sub-directory of custom domain through GitHub

Tags: github, jekyll

I'm trying to set up a personal website (with a custom domain and hosted on GitHub Pages) that would allow me to display the following:

- username.com - custom domain with my own code (not through Jekyll)
- username.com/blog - sub-directory blog (through Jekyll)

I'm not sure how I should go about this. I've tried other online tutorials, but most of them deal with sub-domains (not sub-directories), use the default github.io project domain (not custom domain), or just don't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving the issue myself: I figured out that the main problem I was having was that my `username.com` website was hosted as a **Project Site** and not a **User/Organization Site**. The fix was to create a **User/Organization Site** repository called `username.github.io` and then apply the CNAME/DNS changes redirecting to `username.com`. 
*(A little sad though, I was using `username.github.io` as a testing site.)*

From there, all repositories that are published to `gh-pages` branch would show up as sub-directories of the **User/Organization Site**. If CNAME/DNS was left unchanged, a repository named `blog` would show as `username.github.io/blog`; since I changed CNAME/DNS settings, the repository named `blog` showed up as `username.com/blog`.

Hope that helps anyone else going through similar issues! Good luck all!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is have the following in your Jekyll config file:

```yaml
# _config.yml

url: "https://username.com"
baseurl: "/blog"
```

Then ensure that you use `relative_url` and `absolute_url` filters for your link refs. For example:

```html
<a href="{{ page.url | relative_url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
```

Finally generate a production `_site`:

```sh
bundle exec jekyll build

# or if you don't have a Gemfile
jekyll build
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble getting the GitHub repo to be displayed at `username.com/blog` rather than `username.github.io/blog`?

Comment: Should I be setting the Jekyll site up as a sub-directory of the `username.com` site folder? I currently have it set up as a separate repo called `blog`.